# Click method on Selenium 2.40.2 does not work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium 2.40.2 for testing web application. I need the mouse move and click to draw a polygon on the google map.

The code is below:

```
    bottom_label = browser_drive.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Project']")
    time.sleep(2)
    drawing = ActionChains(browser_drive)\
                    .move_to_element(bottom_label)\
                    .move_by_offset(-650, -600)\
                    .click()\
                    .move_by_offset(100, -100)\
                    .click()\
                    .move_by_offset(300, 0)\
                    .click()\
                    .move_by_offset(0, 400)\
                    .click()\
                    .move_by_offset(-50, -50)\
                    .double_click()\
                    .perform()
    drawing.perform()
    time.sleep(2)
```

The bottom_label used to point the mouse at the end of web page then sleep to start again change offset, click and close the polygon.

This code with Selenium version does not work probably. What should I do to draw the polygon through move and click the mouse?

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times! http://stackoverflow.com/q/24907238/3124333 Instead edit your original question if you are providing additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the new version of Selenium and Firefox.

I changed to the Chrome driver and the click function works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a FluentWait, ImplicityWait and setScriptsTimeout Instead of Sleep.

See further documentation

http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html

Comment: Thank you. It's useful instead of Sleep